# Drupal 7 open image in colorbox when a "button" on the image is clicked, otherwise go to content

Tags: drupal, view, colorbox

I am using Drupal 7 and colorbox module with Views 3. In my view i have an image field. Right now based on my settings when I click the image it can either go to the content or open the image itself in colorbox. What I want to achieve is maybe have a button (or a link?) at the bottom right corner of the image, when this button is clicked, image opens in colorbox, if image itself is clicked, it brings you to the content (node page).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) in you view .. select from FORMAT show: Field

2) insert your field you want .. in this example I will add image, global text, colorbox trigger

3) now will you open a page/overlay page for selected fields

a) on image filed, set a this **Link image to content**, this will be redirect you to content, if you need another page or fixed page (not a content) ..etc, you can chage rewrite result -> check  Output this field as a link and set you link or replace patterns ...

b) in global text filed just set Show Image, we declare a normal div to set custom button

c) now colorbox trigger you can change Trigger field to your global text or (you can select any other field to do trigger), and in **Popup** set a REPLACEMENT PATTERNS for image like [field_cms_image]

and save ...

good luck

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. But in that case the button/link stays under the image, within a div besides image and other fields. How can I move this button/link onto the bottom-right corner of the image? Consider that fact that the height/width of the images are always varying. But the div containing all the fields has fixed height/width.

Comment: you are welcome mate,

I think you can do that by css, and another way is js, Now I suppose css, 

but first can you tell me what is format are used to print a result?
is a table, grid, list ... etc ...

about me I used a very nice show for most of my display - is a responsive grid view, its very nice to control and display data ..
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid

Comment: I am using unformatted list. But I can change it, it is not important because I am displaying one image per view anyways.

Comment: aha, 

if thats, true, and a height is different, for each image .. you can use a js, for get a height, and set a margin-top dependence of height..

the problem here i cant see a fiddle of css snapshot to can give you a height 

*) I cant give you exactly truth way 
since its can be resolved with many of ways .. 
the way is:
1) play with filed, hidden & replacment pattern 
2) css, using relative with image and absolute
3) git height for image by script, and change a position for btn dependence of you image ..
4) clone a btn div and set in same image wrapper, and remove an orginal ..